# Straight line motion: Different acceleration and deceleration rates over a known distance

Tags: kinematics

I have an object that can accelerate at a known rate and decelerate at a different known rate that needs to cover a known distance as quickly as possible.

It must start and end stationary so it would have to accelerate at its acceleration rate for a certain (unknown) distance and then immediately start decelerating at its deceleration rate for the rest of the journey.

How can I work out the time the whole journey would take?

Comment: Consider the velocity $v(t)$ as a function of time.  What will the shape of this function's graph look like?

Comment: A scalene triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t_1$ be the time your object accelerates. Write down a function $f(t_1)$ that gives the time it takes to decelerate to a standstill afterwards. Write down a function $h(t_1)$ that gives the distance covered by this. Set $h(t_1)$ equal to your desired distance, and solve for $t_1$. Plug the solution you find into $t_1+f(t_1)$ and evaluate.

Comment: "Set h(t1) equal to your desired distance, and solve for t1"

Wouldn't that give a time as if it had been decelerating for the whole journey?

Following this I've got t1=square root(s/(-0.5a1^2)) and f(t1)=-a1t1/a2 which doesn't seem to work but it's possible I worked it out wrong.

(I have no idea how to do fancy formatting or line-breaks in comments, sorry).

Comment: @Omegatron: $h(t_1)$ is supposed to be the distance covered by both acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: Ah thanks, got it working now.